# Various ways to relate Latitude and Acceleration due to Gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, centrifugal-force

I was studying the effect of latitude on acceleration due to gravity.

Note: *Please note that in both the parts, the frame of reference chosen is the observer on Earth at that point.*

## Part 1

I tried to derive the relationship in 2 different ways.

Method 1:-

[image]

So here, I think the equation seems nice and good. But now, I tried the same relation in a different manner.

Method 2:-

[image]

Now, I am not getting why am I not able to derive the same equation with this method?  Where am I going wrong?
Everything seems alright to me.

---

## Part 2

While browsing through net, I found another method to derive the same relation and I think many of you are familiar to that.

Website: [Link to tyrocity.com](http://notes.tyrocity.com/variation-of-g-due-to-rotation-or-latitude/)

I found this method in one of my books also.

In this method, I have 2 doubts.

- I don't see the normal force exerted by the ground on the object. **Why?**
- In my 1st part of my post(whether it's my 1st method or 2nd method), the net acceleration vector, g<sub>λ</sub> always acted perpendicular to the surface of Earth but in this part, the net acceleration vector(given in that link) is in a different direction.

---

So, at the end, in both the parts(ignoring the method 2 of part 1), same equation is derived but why g<sub>λ</sub> has different directions?

Answer (score 0):

The net acceleration should not be perpendicular to the surface of the earth (assuming you model the earth as a perfect sphere) as the centrifugal force is perpendicular to the axis of rotation: you need to use vector addition to get the magnitude and direction of the resulting vector. To "think you are vertical", you need to lean "slightly towards the North Pole".

Comment: Okay, I have more doubts but this one is a major one. If I agree on what you are saying that I need to vector sum the weight and centrifugal force acting on that body, then why we are not considering the normal reaction of ground on that object?
Also I did't get this point  <To "think you are vertical", you need to lean "slightly towards the North Pole">.